# Subtracting lowest number from several numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have two numbers. I want the lower number to be the subtracted from both values.

```
x: 1000
y: 200
=> result: x = 800 and y = 0.
```

The following is kinda ugly to me, so is there a better approach I could do this?

```
if (x <= y) {
    y = y - x;
    x = 0
} else {
    x = x - y;
    y = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with those numbers afterwards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int min = Math.min(x, y);
x -= min;
y -= min;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do following:

```
x = x - y;
y = 0;

if(x<0)
{
    y = -x
    x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Duncan's answer, you can use this snippet if you only care about the value that is not going to be zero after the subtraction:

```
int non_zero = Math.abs(x - y); // unless the two are equal of course
```

Comment: Nice. The answer is still correct if the two are equal (IMO).

Comment: @DuncanJones Sure, but `non_zero` would be a misnomer in that case ;)

Comment: @DuncanJones I did consider naming it `most_probably_not_going_to_be_zero` though :P

Answer (score 1):

*How about this*: -

```
int lower = x < y ? x : y;
x -= lower;
y -= lower;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=x-y;
y=y-x;
if(x<0)
    x=0;
else
    y=0;
```

Comment: This would give `y = -600` rather than `y = 0`.